# Trying to add anchor links from other pages to my mvc link

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, anchor

This is my link on our company's asp.net-mvc site:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("OPIE Administrative & Compliance Track", "Index", "OPIECon")
```

I'm fairly new to mvc and am having difficulty finding answers on my own. Right now the link is working fine and directs me to the OPIECon index page. However, I want it to take me to an anchor link ("admin") I've set up on the OPIECon index page. How do I format the above link to make that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) that accepts a `fragment`

```
@Html.ActionLink("OPIE ... Track", "Index", "OPIECon", null, null, "admin", null, null)
```